# Firebase Auth, change password from Android Client or Firebase Function?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm brand new with `Firebase` and I have doubts whether I should change my user's password from the Android Client or a Firebase Function.

Somewhere I read that this very important procedures like updating password, or deleting data shouldnt be done from Android Client but from Firebase Function.

Is it right or doing from Android is safe?

For example in Android you must first authenticate the user before calling the update password method, what if someone bypasses this authentication methods and calls the update method directly, this method receives a password and that's it, it changes the password. However doing all of this from function, there is no way the user can get access to my functions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can send the reset password email to the registered users email..
firebase has a method called

**mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)**

this will send a password reset email to registered users email and the person can reset the password by clicking the link...

Comment: Thanks for the answer I mean when user wants to update his password, my doubt is if calling updatePassword is alright from android client or should I call that method from a function?

Comment: If it's a public method provided by the Android client SDK, then it's meant to be called from the Android client.  The SDK wouldn't provide methods to call that aren't meant to be called.